# Does dell vostro 3500 support ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: dell

I have a Dell Vostro 3500 laptop with Intel I3 processor with 4GB RAM. Can you please tell if I will be able to run Ubuntu 14.04.2 on my laptop? It has Intel Core i3 CPU M380 @ 2.53 Ghz. Installed memory is 4GB(2.93GB usable). System type is 32-bit operating system. Please inform if my laptop will be able to run Ubuntu smoothly. I had earlier used Ubuntu 10.04 on my desktop pc running with Intel Atom processor and 1GB of RAM. Waiting for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu should work great on that computer. You should use Ubuntu 64 bit because you cannot use more than like 3GB RAM with 32 bit. If your laptop has UEFI than it may be hard to install Ubuntu because some UEFI systems make it almost impossible to boot from anything.